# How to change carousel image slider indicators(arrows) color only on the second slide?

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can i change the carousel image slider indicator arrows only on the second image slide???

On the first slide i want to be black color, but when the image slide to 2nd slide i want to set the indicators to white color.

Is this possible???

I tried to create id tag on second slide, but its not helped, someone who is expert in CSS know how to do this???

The big problem is i can't target in CSS only the second slide carousel icons,and i don't know how to do this.

Comment: Please show the code that you tried and what it looks like when run.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the HTML code,this is the Carousel image slider sample:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>


  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="1.jpg"   alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h2 id="fadeuptext" class='animated fadeInUp' style="animation-delay: 1s">Hello</h2>
      <h2 id="fadelefttext" class='animated fadeInLeft' style="animation-delay: 2s">World</h2>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="2.jpg" style="height:797px;"   alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="3.jpg" style="height:797px;"   alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>


  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

And i want to target the second image slider arrow icon in CSS to set the arrow color to white.
carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing your code I cannot be sure, but you should be able to use an nth-child selector like this: .target:nth-child(2) { // styles here }
For more information on nth-child selectors you can check out this article on W3 Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp